# Adding class to dynamically generated div only when specific elements are present - Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I am currently using the [Slick Slider by Ken Wheeler](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to display feature images and video on my website's product detail page. My problem is that I need to target the .slick-slide that has video in it, but am not sure how to do that.

**Here's the HTML**

```
<div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide05" style="width: 735px;" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control05">
  <div class="product-video">
    <video controlslist="nodownload" loop="" muted="" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
      <source src="https://media.djnetworks.net/media/static/dj-includes/images/video/2020/02/2466486_A.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was able to target the inner div and add the class *.product-video* (which I need), but also need to target *.slick-slide* and add the class *.video* to it. Here's what I used to target the inner div.

```
function addVideoClass() {

    // Targets div contain video for mobile slider
    $(".slick-slide > div:has(video)").addClass("product-video");

}
```

Just not sure how to also target the outer div .slick-slide. Any help provided is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're targeting the slide that has the div with the video, you can also either chain back to the parent and add a class or on the next line add the class.

Example 1:

```
// Targets div contain video for mobile slider
$(".slick-slide > div:has(video)").addClass("product-video").parent().addClass("video");
```

Example 2:

```
// Targets div contain video for mobile slider
$(".slick-slide > div:has(video)").addClass("product-video");
$(".slick-slide > div:has(video)").parent().addClass("video");
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/192czL8j/) showing the two options.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the .slick-slide that has a div containing a video

```
$(".slick-slide:has(div:has(video))")
```